# The total number of ways in which six “+” and four ”-“ signs be arranged so that no two “-“ signs occur together is?

Tags: permutations

The total number of ways in which six “+” and four ”-“ signs be arranged so that no two “-“ signs 
occur together is  ?

Comment: Hint: It equivalent to put 4 "-" into 7 spaces (5 between any two "+" and 2 in the head and tail).

Answer (score 2):

Start by writing the $+$ signs, leaving a space between each. Since you don't want adjacent $-$ signs, then we can put at most $1$ minus sign in each available spot. There are $7$ available spots. What can you conclude?

Comment: is d answer 6!P(7,4) according to u?

Comment: Well, how did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: oh yea sry i think dats wrong.......can u tel me d answer?

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: how can u arrange same +signs in 6factorial wys?

Comment: Excellent! If the $+$ signs are identical, there is really only one distinguishable way that we can arrange them. How then would you adjust the answer?

Comment: It is worth noting that your original answer is correct, *if we don't need the arrangements to be distinguishable*.